# Getting error in rust while compiling substrate node-template

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, rust

I am trying to add the staking pallet with other dependencies in node-template and getting this error during compiling, I will be thankful if someone help me to resolve this issue...

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the github repo with your changes? It is hard to debug your error with knowing what changes you have made.

Comment: Please provide more details about the changes you made which led to these errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Bruno https://github.com/Amit22antier/Node-template-consensus.git

Comment: https://github.com/Amit22antier/Node-template-consensus @ShawnTabrizi

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi i was trying to change consensus form Aura to babe in node Template and i was adding pallets like im-online,staking,babe,authority-discovery and other dependency which are required for the changes and i am facing this error while compiling the code .I am sharing the github repo, check it if you can help me out github.com/Amit22antier/Node-template-consensus.git

Comment: Is this still active? I will take a look at the code.

Comment: It was just because of some dependencies which are not currently present in your std features.